# Utilizing Realm Object Server for a collaborative application

Tags: android, ios, swift, mobile, realm

So for the past few days I have been reading through the Realm documentation and I am very excited to use this data synchronization solution in upcoming projects.  After using standard database schemas (SQL, Firebase, etc).  I am still not fully understanding the best way to utilize Realms.  I see Realms are meant to be very flexible, but there are not many examples or docs of how to set up and efficient structure.

So, I wanted to just provide a simple collaborative app idea, and show my first thoughts on how I would set up the Realms. For simplicity, lets say this is a messaging app that contains chatrooms.  Users can create chat rooms and the owner of the room can invite people to their room.  Once that user is added to a room, they will have read/write access to the room.

My current structure:

1) A realm for each user.  (/Users/uid) .  Each one of these realms will have public read access and write access only for the user that owns it.

2) A realm for each chatroom.  (ChatRooms/uid) .  Each chat room will hold the various models pertaining to that specific room (messages, likes, notifications, etc).  Initially only the owner will have read/write access, everyone else will have no access.  The owner can then start handing out read/write permissions to the users they invite.

3) A public realm that holds mappings of a user to a chatroom. (ChatMembers).  This realm will hold models that have two attributes, a user id and a chatroom id.  A user can query this realm by there id to see what chatroom realms they will have access to.

I feel this is a very basic structure, but I am still not positive if this is utilizing Realm to the best of its abilities.  Also, if anyone can lead me to some better documentation, please do.  Would appreciate anyones feedback!!

Answer (score 2):

Refer to: https://docs.realm.io/platform/getting-started-1/android-quick-start/step-4-chat-room-permission-api

Here they have used the permission API and partial sync,to design a chat app that enables the user to create public and private chat rooms.
I would also recommend you to follow the previous steps also mentioned in the above link, to have a basic understanding of how realm works.